# How to add up diff in Carbon in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have all this Carbon diff's (time intervals)

```
$end = Carbon::parse($agentData[$i+1]['created_at']);
$str = Carbon::parse($agentData[$i]['created_at']);
$result['availableTimeDiff'][$agentID][$agentData[$i+1]['lead_id']] = $end->diff($str)->format('%H:%I:%S');


"00:00:08"
"00:00:14"
"00:09:57"
"00:05:45"
"00:00:27"
```

need to sum up all this time in Carbon laravel

Comment: How did you create these values? Can you show the code? This might possibly be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: added them.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not enough to use just 'H:i:s' format.

If all these times add up and the result beyonds 1 day, how to display it.

So I think maybe you can use Carbon diffInSeconds instead of diff method and add up all seconds.

Codes like below:

```
$sumSec = 0;
foreach(... as $i) {
  $end = Carbon::parse($agentData[$i+1]['created_at']);
  $str = Carbon::parse($agentData[$i]['created_at']);
  $result['availableTimeDiff'][$agentID][$agentData[$i+1]['lead_id']] = $end->diffInSeconds($str);
  $sumSec += $result['availableTimeDiff'][$agentID][$agentData[$i+1]['lead_id']];
}
# Do something with $sumSec
```

If you just need the seconds, you can do it like this.

Or you can use the sum seconds and add it to date.

Hope this will help you.